# OPENCV Thresholding

Tags: c++, opencv

I have done thresholding in open cv, but I got a full black color window as output. The command I used is:

```
IplImage* frame = cvLoadImage("threshold.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
IplImage* grayframe = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
cvCvtColor(frame,grayframe,CV_RGB2GRAY);

double thresh = 127;
double maxValue = 255;
double cvThreshold(const CvArr* grayframe,CvArr* dst,double thresh,double maxValue,int CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

Please help me to get the correct output.

Comment: good if you use formatting tools... and make it more clear

Comment: please use opencv's c++ api, code like above should no more be written.

Answer (score 1):

First I advise you to read this carefully
[Threshold_Opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)

Second the `double thresh = 127;` that's mean all the pixels that's `intensity` is less than 127 will be black, and the rest will be white, so try to change the value from 127 to 200 for example and check again.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a function declaration, instead of a function call. Change last line to:

```
cvThreshold(grayframe, dst, thresh, maxValue, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

Full code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    IplImage* frame = cvLoadImage("threshold.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    IplImage* grayframe = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCvtColor(frame, grayframe, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    double thresh = 127;
    double maxValue = 255;
    cvThreshold(grayframe, dst, thresh, maxValue, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    cvShowImage("Threshold", dst);
    cvWaitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

You should, however, avoid to use such obsolete syntax. You can use C++ syntax like:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b frame = imread("threshold.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    Mat1b grayframe;
    cvtColor(frame, grayframe, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    double thresh = 127;
    double maxValue = 255;

    Mat1b dst;
    threshold(grayframe, dst, thresh, maxValue, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    imshow("Threshold", dst);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```